# Fipy Grid3D 'an index can only have a single ellipsis' error

Tags: python, fipy

I am interesting in solving differential equation using fipy.

The following code is working correctly when I am using Grid2D.

```py
from fipy import *

mesh = Grid2D(nx=3, ny=3)
#mesh = Grid3D(nx=3, ny=3, nz=3)
phi = CellVariable(name='solution variable', mesh=mesh, value=0.)
phi.constrain(0, mesh.facesLeft)
phi.constrain(10, mesh.facesRight)
coeff = CellVariable(mesh=mesh, value=1.)

eq = DiffusionTerm(coeff) == 0
eq.solve(var=phi)
```

When I am using Grid3D instead of Grid2D (commented line), I get following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/Programming/python/fdms/forSo.py", line 11, in <module>
    eq.solve(var=phi)
  File "/home/user/Programs/miniconda2/envs/FipyEnv2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fipy/terms/term.py", line 211, in solve
    solver = self._prepareLinearSystem(var, solver, boundaryConditions, dt)
  File "/home/user/Programs/miniconda2/envs/FipyEnv2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fipy/terms/term.py", line 169, in _prepareLinearSystem
    diffusionGeomCoeff=self._getDiffusionGeomCoeff(var),
  File "/home/user/Programs/miniconda2/envs/FipyEnv2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fipy/terms/abstractDiffusionTerm.py", line 458, in _getDiffusionGeomCoeff
    return self._getGeomCoeff(var)
  File "/home/user/Programs/miniconda2/envs/FipyEnv2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fipy/terms/term.py", line 465, in _getGeomCoeff
    self.geomCoeff = self._calcGeomCoeff(var)
  File "/home/user/Programs/miniconda2/envs/FipyEnv2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fipy/terms/abstractDiffusionTerm.py", line 177, in _calcGeomCoeff
    tmpBop = (coeff * FaceVariable(mesh=mesh, value=mesh._faceAreas) / mesh._cellDistances)[numerix.newaxis, :]
  File "/home/user/Programs/miniconda2/envs/FipyEnv2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fipy/variables/variable.py", line 1151, in __mul__
    return self._BinaryOperatorVariable(lambda a,b: a*b, other)
  File "/home/user/Programs/miniconda2/envs/FipyEnv2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fipy/variables/variable.py", line 1116, in _BinaryOperatorVariable
    if not v.unit.isDimensionless() or len(v.shape) > 3:
  File "/home/user/Programs/miniconda2/envs/FipyEnv2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fipy/variables/variable.py", line 255, in _getUnit
    return self._extractUnit(self.value)
  File "/home/user/Programs/miniconda2/envs/FipyEnv2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fipy/variables/variable.py", line 538, in _getValue
    value = self._calcValue()
  File "/home/user/Programs/miniconda2/envs/FipyEnv2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fipy/variables/cellToFaceVariable.py", line 48, in _calcValue
    alpha = self.mesh._faceToCellDistanceRatio
  File "/home/user/Programs/miniconda2/envs/FipyEnv2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fipy/meshes/uniformGrid3D.py", line 269, in _faceToCellDistanceRatio
    XZdis[..., 0,...] = 1
IndexError: an index can only have a single ellipsis ('...')
```

I installed fipy using «Recomended method» from https://www.ctcms.nist.gov/fipy/INSTALLATION.html. I tried to install using Miniconda for both Pthon 3.6 and Python 2.7 and got same errors.

How to solve equations using Grid3D?

Comment: Try rerunning this with the [latest version of FiPy](https://github.com/usnistgov/fipy), say [654426c](https://github.com/usnistgov/fipy/tree/654426c7d472712b628af057ec493d55b9812fbf). The bug may have been fixed on [Jan 12, 2018](https://github.com/usnistgov/fipy/commit/ba26a288f1f426a3e2c0bbe065f163b34cc6805f). With that particular version of FiPy, [654426c](https://github.com/usnistgov/fipy/tree/654426c7d472712b628af057ec493d55b9812fbf), it works for me with both Grid2D and Grid3D.

Answer (score 1):

This is because newer versions of numpy are less tolerant of our sloppy syntax. You can either checkout our [`develop` source branch](https://github.com/usnistgov/fipy) or make [this change](https://github.com/usnistgov/fipy/commit/ba26a288f1f426a3e2c0bbe065f163b34cc6805f#diff-0375f0c03db5da5a99020350b8ea29f6) to your code.